# Can functional component prop be modified?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional component that looks like this:

```
export const Navbarr = ({items}) => {
 

  const [user,  error] = useAuthState(auth);
  const [cartItems, setCartItems]=React.useState(0);

  const fetchUserCartItems=async()=>{
  
      const q = query(collection(db, "users"), where("uid", "==", user?.uid));
      const doc = await getDocs(q);
      const data = doc.docs[0].data();   
      setCartItems(data.cartItems);
      
  }
```

Can "items" be modified with the value of cartItems? And how?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, but it depends what `items` is (array, object etc), and what you need to do to it. This is too far a vague question to be able to answer properly.

Comment: it is a number and I need to update it with the value of another number that I have in state

Comment: You need to add a [mcve]. Where is state? Is it in that component, a parent component? There is nothing to debug here.

Comment: Whichever component owns that state should be passing down a callback that the child component can use to inform it of a new value.

Comment: The parent component which holds `items` will also have a method (for example: `setItems`). If you pass that method along with `items`, then you may invoke/call it to have `items` updated. So, your parent will be like so: `<Navbarr items={parentItems} handleItemsUpdate={setParentItems} ..../>`. And, you would do: `export const Navbarr = ({items, handleItemsUpdate}) => {.....};`. Now, you simply call `handleItemsUpdate` with the parameter as `cartItems`. A better approach will be to avoid having `cartItems` and have only one source of truth (ie, the props `items`).

Comment: I think he wants to send the cartItems back to the parent, yes you can if you put [cartItems, setCartItems] in the parent component and send setCartItems to the Navbarr child as <Navbarr setCartItems={setCartItems}/> and use it in the Navbarr component as: export const Navbarr = (setCartItems) => {.... setCartItems(doc.data().cartItems)...} , now you have the cartItems in the parent component

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify any props rather it can be handle by event handling to change the state.
See this video from the current time duration. After this you know about the event handling and binding.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ke90Tje7VS0&t=3664s